# how to check the if condition with string and integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-conversion

I want to get result of a value with if condition.

i have get some value in xml file.

now what I want is

if I have a variable "a" here i have assigned some values by using dataset.
and i have another variable "b" is assigned value from xml file.

for example
int a=25;
string b=">10"

now I want to check the condition if condition with out ">" because the symbol present in b variable. I dont know how to check this condition can anybody explain me how to acheive this.

I tried like this but not working
if(a+b)

Comment: Is the "b" variable always going to have one leading character? if so you could strip that character off then convert b to an integer then compare them.

Comment: why don't you parse it as int? `int.Parse(b)`

Comment: I tried like this but not working if (a+ int.Parse(bb))  @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: Parse would fail because of the leading character.  As would TryParse.  You need to strip the leading character first.

Comment: I will try@Macron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx)-"trick" to evaulate such expressions:

```
int a = 25;
string b = ">10";
bool isTrue = (bool)new DataTable().Compute($"{a}{b}", null);  // true
```

What is supported you can read at the [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) remarks.

---

> if the condition is 1!=10, how to use not equal in this code .this
>   condition is not working what should i do.

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you that is not valid syntax, you have to use <> (look at operators). So a simple approach would be either to use <> in the first place or replace them:

```
b = b.Replace("!=", "<>");
```

Comment: I understood @Tim Schmelter.  Thanks for advice

Comment: Hi Tim Schmelter if the condition is 1!=10, how to use not equal in this code .this condition is not working what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

You can have some function to remove non numeric characters:

```
public int Parse(string x)
{
  x = Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9.]", "");
  int result = 0;
  int.TryParse(x , out result);
  return result; 
}
```

If its always a number with a symbol then:

```
symbol = b[0];
int bval = int.Parse(b.Substring(1))
```

And considering your comment for comparison you can do:

```
if((symbol=='>'&&a>b)||
   (symbol=='='&&a==b)||
   (symbol=='<'&&a<b)
  ){
       //do your magic here
   }
```

Of course you may need only one of < = > or you may need to have separate if conditions for each, what ever suits your needs, but I just wanted to give the idea.

Comment: I want that symbol also  @Ashkan

Comment: That's only half of the problem and really the easy part.  You also have to inspect `b` for the operator to determine what operation needs to be done to compare `a` to the numeric part of `b`.

Comment: if that's the case this becomes even easier.  You can just use substring to set two separate variables; one for the operator and one for the number, then go on about your day.

Comment: i'm getting error in string symbol = b[0]; cannot implicit convert type char to string –

Comment: Use b[0].ToString() to convrt it to string

Comment: Hi Ashkan Mobayen, here how can i make IF condition if(a+symbol+bval){} if i do this in if condition. i'm getting error. I don't know how to use this in if condition

Answer (score 0):

First separate symbol from b:

```
string symbol = b[0].ToString();
string numberString = b.SubString(1);
int number = int.Parse(numberString);
```

Now use switch to get operation for symbol and compare:

```
bool result = false;
switch (symbol)
{
    case ">":
        if (a > number)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        break;
}
```

EDIT: Changed `symbol` declaration to avoid error: "cannot implicit convert type char to string"

Comment: i'm getting error in string symbol = b[0];  cannot implicit convert type char to string

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this

```
if (b.Contains(">")) {
                                b = b.Replace(">", "");
                                if (a >Convert.ToInt32(b))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("value is less");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("value is Greater");
                                }
                            }
```

similarly all the symbols

Comment: You need to do something like this var operator = b.substring(0); int number = Convert.ToInt32(b.remove(0,1));  if(operator == ">") {if a>number){do stuff}else{do otherstruff}